# Questions about the implementation of the stack exchange family

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Jeff and friends don't owe anyone an explanation of how these sites are built. It could be a room full of trained super-intelligent hamsters moving rep from place to place in return for carrots, for all we know.

If Jeff and friends choose to share their <del>wisdom</del> scars with others by revealing facts about the implementation, that's very nice of them.

I write this discussion topic to suggest that a tag wiki on meta on the subject of the implementation might be a place for the SE crew to write down exactly as much hamster DNA sequence as they choose to reveal, so that the questions that show up, over and over, can be requited by simply inviting the questioners to read it.

Comment: OP's own summary: how to make it easier for the recurring stream of other curious parties to find [What was Stack Overflow Built With?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/)

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is on the blog:

### [What was Stack Overflow Built With?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/)

Also, many of the posts on the [Server Fault blog](http://blog.serverfault.com/) apply, here are a few relevant recent ones:

- [Some Notes on Setting Up Backups with Bacula](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/some-notes-on-setting-up-backups-with-bacula/)
- [DNS: Running our own system – results](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/dns-runing-our-own-system-results/) ([previously](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/1351746720/))
- [Stack Overflow’s New York Data Center](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/1432571770/) (with a network graph, [previously](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/1097492931/))
- [Better Rate Limiting For All with HAProxy](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/1016491873/) ([previously](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/632866473/experiments-in-rate-limiting))

And finally, in the FAQ:

- [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Comment: Yes, I know that. The question is, how to make it easier for the recurring stream of other curious parties to find it.